# Apostol's Calculus volume 1, 2.13 exercise 16

Tags: calculus

This is a problem from Apostol's calculus, I have figured out how to find the volume, but not sure about the sketch, what am I supposed to sketch exactly? The problem has not given me what the solid is?

"The cross sections of a solid are squares perpendicular to the x-axis with their centers on the axis. If the square cut off at x has edge $2x^{2}$, find the volume of the solid between $x = 0$ and $x = a$. Make a sketch."

Comment: and by similar triangles I'd get $s= \dfrac{L}{h}\cdot x= \dfrac{2x^{2}}{x} \cdot x = 2x^{2}$ ? I don't get how did we know from this problem that the length of the base would be $2x^{2}$?

Comment: I retract my original interpretation.  The figure must have curved sides since the cross-section $x$ units to the right of the origin has vertices $(x, x^2, x^2)$, $(x, x^2, -x^2)$, $(x, -x^2, -x^2)$, and $(x, -x^2, x^2)$.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am kinda confused. If we were to draw it 2D would it be a parabola? then we'd imagine it has a square cross section?

Comment: If you were to take a cross section along the $x$-axis, the figure would lie between two parabolas that bend away from the axis.

Answer (score 1):

The volume is bounded by the following curves:

$z = x^2, z = -x^2, y = x^2, y = -x^2$ and x from 0 to a.

There are two parabolas one on positive z axis and one on the negative z axis.  Similarly one on the positive y axis and one on the negative y axis.  Hence when you view along the x axis towards the origin, you find a tunnel with square cross sections at each x value.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I only now noticed your answer. I tried sketching this using GeoGebra but when viewing along the x-axis towards the origin I didn't see a tunnel with square cross sections.. I am very confused

Comment: In fact the "Tunnel" is closed at the origin.  When you the tunnel at a certain value of x, say 5, the first equation will give you z = 25 which is a straight line segment.  Similarly, the second equation will give you z = -25 which is another straight line segment but this time in the lower quadrant.  The third equation will give you y = 25 which is another line segment vertically.  The fourth equation will give you another line segment y = -25.  This 4 line segments will give you a square of line 50 or 2x^2.  This is true for any value of x when x > 0.

Comment: Although I am still having trouble to graph it, but I think I somehow understood what you meant.